# Connect to .FDB database using PHP

Tags: php, wamp, firebird

This is my configuration:

- Windows 7 64 bits
- WAMP Server 2.2 64 bits with PHP 5.4.3 (downloaded from official site).
- Firebird 1.5.6 to manage database (I need this version because newer versions don't open my db's). This program has only a 32 bit version (downloaded from official site).

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-connect.php) is the code to connect to a FDB database. But when I try the code, I get the error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in..."

I try:

- Activate the php_interbase.dll extension (WAMP->PHP->PHP Extensions->php_interbase.dll).
- Add an Environment Variable in Windows to the PHP.ini folder.
- Add an Environment Variable in Windows to the Firebird folder.
- Use Firebird 2.5 64 bits.
- Edit the php.ini file, deleting the semicolon to line ;extension=php_interbase.dll.
- Follow [this](http://www.alberton.info/firebird_php_windows.html#.U6iBdfl5OGI) steps.

And anything works. I get the same error. After of each tip I try, obviously I restart WAMP.

**Note:** when I execute (in a PHP page) extension_loaded("interbase"), I get always false. When the extension is loaded and when it isn't loaded. I think that it is the problem, but how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want newer version of Firebird to open your database, then you need to make a backup in Firebird 1.5.6 and restore it with the new Firebird version. Technically Firebird should be able to open databases of older versions though (although with older versions there might be issues with 32 bit <> 64 bit), but backing up and restoring will ensure the database is upgraded to the newer on disk structure.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look at the SourceForge downloads for firebird I can see that the only 1.5.6-release download is a 32bit compile.

This will not run on a 64bit WampServer as that means that Apache/PHP + extensions/MySQL were all compiled with a 64bit compiler.

If you have to have that version of firebird running then you will need to download a 32bit WAMPServer because 32bit Firebird will not interface with a 64bit firebird PHP extension.

There is no real benefit to running the 64bit WAMPServer i.e. Apache/PHP/MySQL its really only there for the geeks. In fact 64bit PHP is still described as **Experimental** on the PHP web site, as it has not yet been fully ported to 64bit.

Comment: Technically it should work, as long as a 64 bit client library is installed and on the library path, and the connection is made over TCP/IP (and not a direct/native connection).